# C# & PLSQL - Finding Comments and Strings by RegExp

Tags: regex, string, plsql, comments

Is it possible to distinguish between code, strings and comments by using regular expressions?
I'm trying to build a formatter for PLSQL-Code in C# and I can't manage to solve the problem, that strings, respectively quotes ( " or ' ) can also appear in comments, negating their special character and vice versa, comment indicators ( -- or /* ) appearing in strings, being nullified as a special character sequence.
Is there a solution, or are regular expressions simply the wrong way to handle this?

Best regards,
Philipp

Comment: I guess that's one of those times you're better off with a parser than using RegEx

Comment: Don't forget the alternative quoting mechanism.  For example: `select q'['test--]' from dual;` `select q'!'test/*!' from dual;`  Every syntax highlighting editor I've ever used has failed to work properly with strings like that.

Answer (score 1):

You might find an idea how to reliably identify comments by studying a source code of Perl module [Regexp::Common::comment](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2011041701/lib/Regexp/Common/comment.pm). The module supports matching also PL/SQL comments.